# Interpolating Temperature over Elevation on ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, interpolation, elevation, kriging

I need to overlay or create a new image file in ArcGIS that overlays temperature point data I have for California onto a 30m resolution DEM for that state. I have explored Co-Kriging, however I have not been able to firmly create a final product in which the temperature data is even remotely close to conformed to elevation. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Neither of build in interpolation will work. Search net for software by Hutchinson called anusplin. It interpolates point data and takes dem into account.

Comment: Another much cheaper option is exploring relationship between temperature and elevation ONLY. Can be done in excel. Apply derived function on dem using raster calculator

Comment: Thank you both for these options! @FelixIP, since my project is on a budget, ill approach your solution first. Your suggestion was my original thought and how I wanted to approach it. However, im not sure what my derived function would be. Do you have any ideas as how I should make this equation?

Comment: Both suggestions are from me:) Anyway first drive altitude of the stations by sampling dem. Bring table to excel and plot temperature vs altitude using scatter plot. Add tend line and equation preferably linear. With polynomial be careful function does not have minimum within dem range

Comment: Oh god @FelixIP, as you can see I'm a bit tired :)! If I had the altitudes of the stations pre-canned within my text file, I assume I could use those as opposed to deriving from the DEM. Next question, once I achieve a linear regression equation, how would I apply that within the raster calculator in ArcMap?

Comment: Your altitude has to be consistent with dem, thus sample. In raster calculator replace x in regression equation by name of your dem in the table of content

Comment: @FelixIP, you're a lifesaver, thank you so much! I'll be testing this out later today. I think I have a good approach ready to go now, can I bother you once more here or via an email if I have any more questions ?